# Change Cognito Forms status from Incomplete to Reviewed

Tags: cognito-forms

We have some user submitted forms where the status shows as Incomplete, but there's nothing in the form data that was submitted that I can see that would cause the form submission to be Incomplete.

For administrative purposes, we really need to be able to change these to either Reviewed, or Submitted. Is there a way to do this? Can't find any way so far.

Also, wondering if a user possibly saved a form instead of submitting it, intending to come back later and complete and then submit it, but didn't get back to it. Would this cause the form submission to be Incomplete?

Answer (score 1):

Entries that have been saved (via the Save & Resume feature), but have not yet been finalized or submitted, will appear with a status of Incomplete. Once the user submits their entry, the status will change to Submitted. You can also change entries back to Incomplete if necessary.

If you want to change the entries to reviewed or submitted, you can open the Individual entry and select Edit, then Submit to manually submit the entry.

Comment: Gee.. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, this workflow is very intentional, as changing the status from Incomplete to Submitted triggers email notifications and other workflow associated with submissions.  The reason you cannot simple change the status is that the Incomplete entry may have validation errors that need to be corrected first.

Comment: Yep... that makes sense...